# How do I get my DVD drive back after upgrading from windows 7 to 8?

Tags: linux, windows-8, dvd, device-manager

When upgrading my Toshiba Satellite P755-S5263 from Windows 7 to 8 my DVD drive disappeared. It is not visible in Device Manager or anywhere else at all - just as if there wasn't one. I configured my computer to dual boot to both Windows 8 and Kubuntu, and the DVD drive still works when Kubuntu is loaded.

I have tried the registry edits and other suggestions I can find online.

Comment: How about the [driver](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/downloads/OS2015028A_TC30807900A.exe) made specifically for your laptop's drive?

Comment: @Insane it would show in device manager even if there is no driver.

Comment: @Moab You would expect that

Comment: If it isn't showing up something is happening that is causing Windows to not even attempt to detect it.  If the device can be removed, Windows started, then connected again that might trigger something.  Windows has a nasty habit though of remembering about devices if nothing changes about them though.

Comment: @Insane If it does not show in device manager then no driver will help.

Comment: @Insane, Thanks for your suggestion. When I tried to install the Blue ray driver you referenced it said no such device detected.

Comment: @Ramhound, I shut off the computer, removed the drive, rebooted, scanned for new hardware, shut off the computer, replaced the drive, rebooted, and scanned for new hardware again with no result. I dried hot removal and scanning also with no result.